# List.IndexOf returns -1 after deleted item in listview

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

okay so i have a List of items that is viewed in a ListView. I am using the index of the of the selected item in the listview.

"List.IndexOf(ListView.SelectedItem)". From this i store the index as the "id" to the database i am using to retreive information later on etc..

The problem comes when i delete one item from the ListView. The delete process works fine but after i have deleted an item, "List.IndexOf(ListView.SelectedItem)" is returning -1 (until i restart the app) rather than the index of where the item is placed in the listview. Why is this? is there any way around this? like refreshing the whole view or something?

```
    <mr:ListView x:Name="exampleListView" LongPressing="I_LongPressing">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ImageCell Text="{Binding mainSite}" TextColor="Black" Detail="{Binding link}" ImageSource="{Binding image}"></ImageCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</mr:ListView>
```

---

```
Items = new List<ListViewItem>();
int itemValue = Items.IndexOf(exampleListView.SelectedItem); //this will return -1 if i delete an item from ListView aka the List (Items)
```

---

Delete code of item in list that was suggested in comments!

```
public async void I_LongPressing(object sender, MR.Gestures.LongPressEventArgs e)
    {
        var result = await DisplayAlert("Delete", "Are you sure you want to delete this object?", "Delete", "Cancel");
        if (result == true)
        {
            ListViewItem k = (ListViewItem)exampleListView.SelectedItem;
            dataBase.Query<ListViewItem>(string.Format("DELETE FROM [ListViewItem] WHERE [link] = '{0}'", k.link));

            int itemValue = Items.IndexOf(exampleListView.SelectedItem);
            dataBase.Query<ObjectAndNote>(string.Format("DELETE FROM [ObjectAndNote] WHERE item = '{0}'", itemValue));
            Update();
        }
    }

    public async void Update()
    {
        string path = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
        var asyncCon = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(path + "/TestDB.dc3");

        exampleListView.ItemsSource = new List<ListViewItem>();
        List<ListViewItem> refreshedList = await asyncCon.QueryAsync<ListViewItem>("SELECT * FROM ListViewItem");
        await asyncCon.QueryAsync<ObjectAndNote>(string.Format("UPDATE ObjectAndNote SET item = 'item--'"));
        if (refreshedList.Count != 0)
        {
            exampleListView.ItemsSource = refreshedList;
        }
    }
```

Kind Regards

Comment: I deleted my answer because I realize now that you're doing far more than simply working with a ListView object. I don't understand why you are storing UI information in your database--that is the kind of data the ListViewItem table appears to contain. That's a really bad idea--especially if you have more than one user. Bind your UI to the ObjectAndNote table--and that's it. Comments?

Comment: Got example code? There is only one user ! ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

every time you delete, you then do this to refresh your data

```
List<ListViewItem> refreshedList = await asyncCon.QueryAsync<ListViewItem>("SELECT * FROM ListViewItem");
```

this creates a **new list** of **new items** that are unique objects that are **not** the same as the objects previously stored in the list.

Instead of using `IndexOf`, which looks for a specific instance of an object, try querying the list by the ID or some other unique element to find it's place in the list.  Or, instead of refreshing the entire list, just update the existing list to remove the deleted item.

Comment: My idea at first was to update the list so that they just would be refreshed. But i dont know how to do that. Didn't find a command for it. Do you have an example on how to do it?

Comment: I tried something like this but after i click the delete popup button. I get this error "Object refrence not set to an instance of an object" https://pastebin.com/5KvdzwQy

Comment: which specific line throws the exception?

Comment: Hard to tell because the application is going into "break" mode. But it has something to do when selecting an item after i have deleted one. so that would be the itemselected event. https://pastebin.com/syrENe6B